# Sensor Module misbehaving when connected to a voltage divider

Tags: voltage-divider, comparator

I am using this sensor module with Raspberry Pi 3
http://www.sunrom.com/p/optical-slot-sensor
Since this is a 5V sensor, I connected a Voltage Divider circuit. But the sensor misbehaved. The output wouldn't change. I inserted a diode between the resistors and ground.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgv0dp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
Schema of sensor module:
[image: Schema of the sensor module]

Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: Now draw your divider on top of the circuit with proper connection and try to calculate. And I have no idea that is that intuition making you to put this diode..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparator LM393 has an open collector output. It can only pull down the output, therefore a pull-up resistor is needed to provide a high level signal. In your case this is the 10k resistor in parallel to the LED with the 1k resistor.

As soon as you add 2x330ohm = 660ohms to the output you effectively disable the pull-up network, because this resistance is lower than that of the pull-up network. Since the comparator also can only pull-down the signal, you can't get a high signal anymore.

The added diode is reverse biased and therefore disables the 2x 330ohms resistors. It's the same as if there were no resistors at all.

By the way, the page you link to says that the module can be operated with 3.3V.

A simplified schematic of the comparator taken from [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm393.pdf) is shown below. It should make clear, why your modification doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Agreed. Also note that when the diode is added there is no divider anymore so you may feed 5 V into the Pi. The GPIO might not last long.

Comment: Although the current into the I/O is limited to 15 mA due to the 330 R in series. Using a lower supply voltage seems the obvious choice, but if that's not possible for some reason, you can use a transistor or open-collector buffer to level shift.

Comment: thanks guys... i just verified and thats whats exactly happening. There was a 5V in the output

Answer (score 1):

The circuit board has an LM393 comparator IC, which has an open collector output. Looking at the schematic diagram you provided, the output stage looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7I9lt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transistor in the LM393's output functions like a switch that connects/disconnects the LM393's output pin to/from GROUND. So let's redraw this schematic, replacing the transistor in the LM393's output with a SPST toggle switch:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpo3kP.png)</sup>

Note that when SW1 is closed (i.e., when the transistor in the LM393's output is ON), the voltage at node DO is zero Volts.

How would you modify this circuit so that when switch SW1 is open (i.e., when the transistor in the LM393's output is OFF), the voltage at node DO is 3.3 Volts? (HINT: The solution requires the addition of a single resistor assuming no other current sources/loads are connected to node DO.)

Comment: Add a 2k between out and ground. :-)

Comment: Nope. Try again. The resistor's placement is correct, but not its value.

Comment: Am getting 1.8k

Comment: We might be using different values for the LED's forward voltage drop, VF, and that's why we're getting different results. I selected at random an amber LED whose nominal forward voltage drop is VF=2.1V @ 20mA. When VOUT=3.3V, the voltage across the LED and 1k resistor is 5V-3.3V=1.7V, which (a) is not enough voltage to illuminate the LED, and (b) is below the LED's knee voltage. So when VOUT=3.3V the LED's forward current IF is probably only tens of microamps (say, 50uA). The current through R1 is (5-3.3)/10k=170uA. Therefore, Rx's value must be 3.3V/(170uA+50uA)=15k.

Comment: Thank you @jim-fischer , I was not considering resistance across diode.